# How to Get multiple values from a Managed Metadata Column in SharePoint using PnP Powershell

Tags: pnp-powershell

There seem to be many examples of this, but none in PnP PowerShell.  I'm trying to access all of the values from a column that is using the Term Store.  I'm on SharePoint 2013

Here is my code this far:

```
 $libs = Get-PnPList -Web $web | Where{($_.BaseType -eq “DocumentLibrary”) }

          foreach($lib in $libs){
             $libitems = (Get-PnPListItem -Web $web -List $lib -Fields "FileLeafRef","Name","Title","Author","Modified","Created","KBAbstract","KBContentAuthor","KBCategory","Publish","KBPublishDate").FieldValues

               foreach($libitem in $libitems)
                 {
                     if($libitem.FSObjType -eq "0"){
                      $data = @{
                                  ...                          
                                   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection]$MMSFieldValueColl = $libitem["KBCategory"] 
                                    #Concatenate each term in the value collection
                                    $MMSFieldTerms = ""
                                    Foreach ($MMSFieldValue in $MMSFieldValueColl)
                                    {
                                        if($MMSFieldValue.label -ne $null)
                                        {
                                            $MMSFieldTerms+=$MMSFieldValue.label+"; "
                                        }
                                    }
....
```

I'm getting an error on my Foreach() statement:

> Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection]` typecasting is incorrect and not needed because PnP PowerShell does that for you.

You can simply iterate over `$MMSFieldValueColl` and fetch the values as below:

```
$MMSFieldValueColl = $libitem["KBCategory"] 

#Concatenate each term in the value collection

$MMSFieldTerms = ""
Foreach ($MMSFieldValue in $MMSFieldValueColl)
{
    if($MMSFieldValue.Label -ne $null)
    {
        $MMSFieldTerms+=$MMSFieldValue.Label+"; "
    }
}
Write-host $MMSFieldTerms
```

UPDATE _________________________

```
function PopulateData($web, $incldeFileSize){
        Write-Host "Current Site " $web.url -ForegroundColor Cyan 
                  $libs = Get-PnPList -Web $web | Where {($_.BaseType -eq “DocumentLibrary”) }

                  foreach($lib in $libs){
                     $libitems = (Get-PnPListItem -Web $web -List $lib -Fields "FileLeafRef","Name","Title","Author","Modified","Created","KBAbstract","KBContentAuthor","KBCategory","Publish","KBPublishDate").FieldValues

                       foreach($libitem in $libitems)
                         {
                             if($libitem.FSObjType -eq "0"){
                              $data = @{
                                          "Web Name" = $web.Title

                                          "Library Name" = $lib.Title
                                          "File Name" = $libitem.FileLeafRef
                                          "Abstract" = $libitem.KBAbstractMicrosoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
                                            $value = $libitem["KBContentAuthor"]
                                            $user = Get-PnPUser -Identity $value.LookupId
                                           "Content Author" = $user.Title
                                           $MMSFieldValueColl = $libitem["KBCategory"] 
                                            #Concatenate each term in the value collection
                                            $MMSFieldTerms = ""
                                            Foreach ($MMSFieldValue in $MMSFieldValueColl) {

                                                if($MMSFieldValue.label -ne $null)
                                                {
                                                    $MMSFieldTerms+=$MMSFieldValue.label+"; "
                                                }
                                            }
                                            Write-Host $MMSFieldTerms

                                         # "Knowledge Area" = $libitem.KBCategory
                                          "Publish" = $libitem.Publish
                                          "Published Date" = $libitem.KBPublishedDate.LookupValue
                                          "File URL" = $libitem.FileRef
                                          "Modified Date" = $libitem.Modified
                                          "Created By" = $libitem.Author.LookupValue
                                          "Created Date" = $libitem.Created
                                          "Modified By" = $libitem.Editor.LookupValue
                                          "File Size (KB)" = $null
                                     }
                             if($incldeFileSize -eq $true){
                                    $file = Get-PnPFile -Url $libitem.FileRef
                                    $data["File Size (KB)"] = $file.Length / 1KB
                              }
                              New-Object PSObject -Property $data
                            }
                         }
                  }       
}
```

Comment: Hi Gautam.  I'm removed the cast yet I'm still gettiing the same error at the beginning of the Foreach statement.  All of the code was working until I added the lines above.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why its not working. Formatting seems to be correct. I tried a similar code with different column names and it worked. Can you try it for a single item as `$listItem = (Get-PnPListItem -List "Documents" -Id 30).FieldValues` and test it and then try it inside the loop. Do note, i have SP Online and not 2013, so probably something could be different :(

Comment: Guatam... Can you check the update to the question?  I've posted the entire function.  Thanks!

Comment: code seems fine, i tested with different column names and it works fine ! Did you try the above code in the comment above ?

Comment: Hi Gautam, I resolved this issue by moving the foreach block that collects the $MMSFieldValues out of the Hash Table $data.  Apparently, it only accepts name-value pairs.  Thanks!